# fibnoacci test case issue- Python

Tags: python, algorithm, fibonacci

For running, the test code of **4**, answers should be **3** per leet code. Per algoexpert.io shows the output to be **2** as it's correct on there test-code. Which one is correct? If so, please explain and rectify the algorithm.

```py
n = 4
    
def getNthFib(n):
    lastTwo = [0 , 1]
    counter = 3
    while counter <= n:
        nextFib = lastTwo[0] + lastTwo[1]
        lastTwo[0] = lastTwo[1]
        lastTwo[1] = nextFib
        counter += 1
    return lastTwo[1] if n > 1 else lastTwo[0]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    getNthFib(n)
    print(getNthFib(n))
```

Thank you

Comment: Is your question "what is the fourth Fibonacci number"? Why not look on Wikipedia?

Comment: @kaya3 that's not what I asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are correct. The answer depends on the start of the sequence. If you start it with `0,1`, then the 4th item will be 2 and if you start with `1,1`, then the 4th item will be 3.

**EDIT:**

I made small changes to your code:

```
def getNthFib(n):
  if n==0: return 0
  lastTwo = [1 , 1]
  counter = 3
  while counter <= n:
    nextFib = lastTwo[0] + lastTwo[1]
    lastTwo[0] = lastTwo[1]
    lastTwo[1] = nextFib
    counter += 1
  return lastTwo[1] if n > 1 else lastTwo[0]
```

Comment: Leet code doesn't accept the code starting from 1,1 as their test code includes 0 and the code fails. @Aniket Tiratkar

Comment: In that case the sequence is starting with `0,1,1` and their indexing is starting from `0`. It is same as starting the sequence with `1,1` and indexing from `1`. Only difference is that you will have to add a condition for `n=0`. Check my edited answer for solution.